# does any call to node js must end with response?

Tags: node.js, express

I got a post function to add new user. I dont see any need to return anything to the client. Will the node thread stuck until he find a respond to send back? Is this a good approach?

(I use express)

```
app.post('/newUser',function(req,res){
        users.push(req.body.user);
    });
```

Comment: Really, you do need to send a response. How will the client know if the database was busy, for example, or if the user you are adding already exists, etc., etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always return something to the client. The client waits for a response.

In the case of adding a user, you could return the created user or, if it fails, an error message.

Comment: okay I agree but will the server thread stuck until I response back?

Comment: Not the server, probably the client.. But even for the server, is good to close the connections. so you should at least close the connection, even if you do not send anything. `res.end()` would do.